# Meaning of "I'll have it nicely dried"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I can't understand the meaning of the phrase *"I'll have it nicely dried"*.

Does it mean the same as
*"I'll dry it very well"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chambers gives a definition of **nice** as *done with great care and exactness* and I think the element of 'care' is relevant here. The person will be taking care to ensure that whatever it is is dried and ready for use. 
**Nicely** ( or the variant of **nice and...**) personalises what would otherwise be a bald statement of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be you but some other person or the nature (wind, sun) that dries the thing.

You could have it dried by your mother, for example.